# Have error message show when form is created through AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a page called `/add` that you can add a `Dog` on and the form is in its own partial. I'm using [Simple Form](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). I added the files for the main Bootstrap but [use a gem for simple_form to work with it](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap) just so you know.

DogsController

```
# new.js.erb (deleted new.html.erb)

def new 
 @dog = Dog.new

 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
 end
end

# create.js.erb

def create 
  @dog = current_user.dogs.new(params[:dog])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @dog.save
      format.html { redirect_to add_url, notice: 'Dog was successfully added.' }
      format.json { render json: @dog, status: :created, location: @dog}
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render 'pages/add' }
      format.json { render json: @dog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

dogs/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@dog, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => "shared/error_message", :locals => { :f => f } %>
    <%= f.input :name %>      
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Done' %>
<% end %>
```

This line: `<%= render :partial => "shared/error_message", :locals => { :f => f } %>`

Is for bootstrap so it renders the errors html correctly.

PagesController

```
def add

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

pages/add.html.erb

```
<div id="generate-form">
</div>
```

dogs/new.js.erb

```
$("#generate-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'dogs/form', locals: { dog: @dog })) %>");
```

Now how would I get this to render the error partial as if it was still on my `dogs/new.html.erb` since its being created through AJAX? I don't need client side validations do I?

---

**EDIT**

**shared/_error_message.html.erb**

```
<% if f.error_notification %>
   <div class="alert alert-error fade in">
     <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
     <%= f.error_notification %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through our chat you mentioned you also had a create.js.erb and that file was clearing out the form.

making the  the create.js the same as new.js.erb  :
$("#generate-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'dogs/form', locals: { dog: @dog })) %>");

made it work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do client side validations. But should,it is common to disable the submit button via js until client side validation is met.
also I would not delete the new.html.erb incase a client doesn't.have js turned on.
I think your add may need format.js to your add and
remote = true to your shared errors partial call

Comment: I added the `remote => true` to my error partial: `<%= render :partial => "shared/error_message", :locals => { :f => f }, :remote => true %>` and `format.js` to the `add` block but no luck. I even tried to put it in my dogs `else` clause when creating.

Comment: Add an html comment outside of the conditional in the errors partial then view the source of the /add page to see if it is being brought in the first place.

Comment: when you submit the form is it doing an.Ajax request?

Comment: Yeah it does because I can still create things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12773/discussion-between-alex-and-railslearner)